# How to convert my list variable from a tuple to a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

i am getting the following error:

index 0 has type 'tuple' but 'str' is expected

My list variable looks like this:

[('304',), ('316',), ('303',), ('BS S130',), ('Do Not Use',), ('17-4PH',), ('431S29',), ('416',), ('304',), ('316',), ('S143D',), ('15/5PH-H1025',), ('304S11',), ('316S11',), ('304L',), ('316L',), ('304S16',), ('BS S527',), ('316L',), ('316',), ('Misc',)]

```
def stainless_list(self):
    stainless_getlist = []

    content = 'SELECT grade FROM stainless ORDER BY prefix ASC'
    res = conn.execute(content)
    for row_index, row_data in enumerate(res):
        stainless_getlist.append(row_data)

    conn.close

    self.comboBox_2.clear()
    self.comboBox_2.addItems(stainless_getlist)

    print(stainless_getlist)
    return
```

How do i declare my list as a string instead of tuple so that it attaches to my combobox correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unpack the first item of each tuple as you iterate over the rows (and you don't need to `enumerate` as you are not using the row index).

Change:

```
for row_index, row_data in enumerate(res):
    stainless_getlist.append(row_data)
```

to:

```
for item, in res:
    stainless_getlist.append(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your list is a list of tuples, where each tuple is a row of data.  What may be confusing is that the output of your select is a list of rows, with only one value in each row. Try this:

```
for row in res:
   stainless_getlist.append( row[0] )
```

The 1st row is tuple containing one string `('304',)`  not just a string `'304'`.